# Hosting a directory of legacy static HTML files on Drupal

Tags: routes

My clients has a folder of static HTML files from 1999. I want to upload the folder to Drupal and then use an iframe to frame it in. I know it sounds awful but that's all he has the budget for. How can I get Drupal to ignore the entire directory and serve up the files "as is"? It is required that the files be hosted on the same domain.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're using the default rewrite rules you don't need to do anything.

Drupal's .htaccess file contains this:

```
# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
# index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

So requests for existing files won't be re-written, the file will just be served.